# Doing UPDATE using a SELECT statement with GROUP_CONCAT within the same table

Tags: mysql, drupal, select

I'm trying to update a database table within MySQL to combine rows. Here's what part of the table looks like:

```
NID     SID     CID     NO      DATA  
5297    32002   5   0   10  
5297    32002   5   1   17  
5297    32002   5   2   1976
```

The 'DATA' column contains the month, day, and year that make up a date. So I would like to combine those records into the following:

```
5297    32002   5   0   10-17-1976
```

For each SID, it contains a CID with 3 different rows, indicated by the 'No' column and containing the three parts of the date.

I can get the output desired with this select statement:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( d.data ORDER BY `no` SEPARATOR '-') AS data FROM
webform_submitted_data_copy d WHERE cid = "5" GROUP BY d.sid
```

This returns what is desired to be in the 'data' column following an UPDATE..but I can't figure out how to form the correct UPDATE statement... Something like:

```
UPDATE webform_submitted_data_copy 
SET webform_submitted_data_copy.data = (GROUP_CONCAT( d.data ORDER BY `no` SEPARATOR '-'))
WHERE webform_submitted_data_copy.cid = "5" GROUP BY webform_submitted_data_copy.sid
```

But this affects 0 rows, and has no failures...tried many other possible statements with no joy.

???

Anyone know what I need to do in order to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you don't really want an `UPDATE` statement. After you run an `UPDATE`, your table still has the same number of records as before; but it sounds like you want it to end up with one-third as many records as it started with. (Right?)

So I think your best bet is to create a temporary table; something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE webform_submitted_data_copy_temp
SELECT d.nid, d.sid, d.cid, GROUP_CONCAT( d.data ORDER BY `no` SEPARATOR '-') AS data FROM
webform_submitted_data_copy d WHERE cid = "5" GROUP BY d.sid;

UPDATE webform_submitted_data_copy
   SET data =
        ( SELECT data
            FROM webform_submitted_data_copy_temp
           WHERE sid = webform_submitted_data_copy.sid
        )
 WHERE cid = '5'
   AND no = 0
;

DELETE webform_submitted_data_copy
 WHERE cid = '5'
   AND no > 0
;

DROP TABLE webform_submitted_data_copy_temp;
```

Comment: You should actually create a `TEMPORARY` table in your SQL there. ;)

Comment: (And I'm not sure if you can use `TEMPORARY` in the `CREATE ... SELECT` syntax. But for obvious reasons, I didn't want to use `TEMPORARY` in the version that `DROP`ped the original table, anyway. In the new version, that would be fine, if it works.)

Comment: Thanks ruakh! That worked. I should of thought of just copying to another table for this operation....thanks!